# Webdriver C# how to set driver timeouts with multiple browsers

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver, nunit

Hoping to find my answer here I have spent the better half of a week trying to figure this out myself and I cannot fix my issue. A little background, I am new to C# and NUnit tests with webdriver, I am attempting to create a regression suit for the company I work for. We have a few products that are heavily integrated with ebay and so for part of the test I need to click on a button which takes me to the ebay login page and then I need to login. Seems simple enough (or so I thought). The issue I am running into is when hitting this ebay login page FF times out each time. I currently have my test setup to run in multiple browsers, chrome and IE are passing (they also hang a little) but FF has never passed.

This is odd to me because earlier in this test I go to ebay and sucessfully login. But when I have to link my company account to the ebay account this login page takes forever. I know we pass some unique token to ebay to link the accounts which is what I think causes the long load times.

So the failure with FF is always the same, timed out after 60 seconds. I have read other questions that seemed to be a similar issue ([Selenium WebDriver throws Timeout exceptions sporadically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268255/selenium-webdriver-throws-timeout-exceptions-sporadically)) there are a few solutions the one I am interested in is setting the driver timeout to something greater than 60 seconds. I do not know how to do this with multiple browser setup I have going.

```
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
public class UnitTest1<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver: IWebDriver, new()
{
     PTGeneral General;
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        General = new PTGeneral();
        General.Driver = new TWebDriver();

    }
```

I would really like to keep this setup as I like how I can test IE, FF, and Chrome, but I do not know how to implement a solution like this then.

```
 new FirefoxDriver("FfBinaryPath", FfProfileInstance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if you would like more information ill be happy to provide, assuming I understand what you are asking ;)

Thank you all for even reading, this community is amazing.

Still struggling with this one. Here is the error message if that helps.

```
------ Run test started ------
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started
Loading tests from C:\Users\jburns\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PTTest\PTTest\bin\Debug\PTTest.dll
Run started: C:\Users\jburns\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PTTest\PTTest\bin\Debug\PTTest.dll
TearDown failed for test fixture PTTest.UnitTest1<ChromeDriver>
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:64706/session/0186901c828d3a1ad7523ecd41dedf9a/element timed out after 60 seconds.
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByXPath(String xpath)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.<XPath>b__c(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at PTTest.PTGeneral.IsElementPresent(By by) in c:\Users\jburns\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PTTest\PTTest\PTGeneral.cs:line 42
   at PTTest.PTGeneral.EmailCleanUP() in c:\Users\jburns\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PTTest\PTTest\PTGeneral.cs:line 105
   at PTTest.UnitTest1`1.TearDown() in c:\Users\jburns\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PTTest\PTTest\UnitTest1.cs:line 29
TearDown failed for test fixture PTTest.UnitTest1<FirefoxDriver>
```

So I stripped out the multiple browser piece I had in the [TestFixture] and setup so that I could test only against FF and increased the driver timeout to 3m with

```
General.Driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), new FirefoxProfile(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

This worked and made my tests pass. But I still need a solution that works when I run against multiple browsers, as I don't want to maintain 2 different projects when there should be a way to

Comment: Please show how you navigate to this page that loads a long time. Show how you clicks on the button.

Comment: Well I got a solution to this issue. The way I was able to get around it is by increasing the SetPageLoadTimeout(). Then I captured the link from the button that triggered the page load and called the new page via the GoToUrl() call which respects the timeout set by SetPageLoadTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have to wait till a page is loading.

Then the solution will be to use waiting methods each time when a new page is being opening.

**Put this method after navigating to each new page:**

```
        public void WaitForPageLoading(int secondsToWait = 600)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            try
            {
                while (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < secondsToWait)
                {
                    var pageIsReady = (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState == 'complete'");
                    if (pageIsReady)
                        break;
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Driver.Dispose();
                throw new TimeoutException("Page loading time out time has passed " + secondsToWait + " seconds");
            }
            finally
            {
                sw.Stop();
            }
        }
```